# How do I get secondary colours to work in tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, jquery, css, tailwind-css

Before I start please bear in mind I am very new to web development and have just been messing around with tailwind for the last 4-5 hours I am just playing around to figure it out but I cannot understand what is going wrong here.

I have installed Tailwind CSS to my folder as per the instructions on their website and I am pretty sure my config is correct.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Johari's Window Exercise</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@alpinejs/collapse@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-teal-600">
  <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl m-4">Johari's Window</h1>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">Johari's window is an exercise that is used to improve self-awareness and understanding between individuals. It was created by psychologists Joseph Luft and Harry Ingham in 1955.</p>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">The exercise involves four quadrants, each representing a different aspect of an individual's self-awareness:</p>

  <div class='flex items-center justify-center' x-data="{ reportsOpen: false }">
    <div class='w-full max-w-lg px-10 py-8 mx-auto bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl'>
      <div class='max-w-md mx-auto space-y-6'>
        <img src='https://tailwindcomponents.com/svg/logo-color.svg' class='h-8' />

        <p class='text-gray-600'></p>

        <div @click="reportsOpen = !reportsOpen" class='flex items-center text-gray-600 w-full border-b overflow-hidden mt-32 md:mt-0 mb-5 mx-auto'>
          <div class='w-10 border-r px-2 transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out' :class="{'rotate-90': reportsOpen,' -translate-y-0.0': !reportsOpen }">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
                        </svg>
          </div>
          <div class='flex items-center px-2 py-3'>
            <div class='mx-3'>
              <button class="hover:underline">This is where you click to open</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex p-5 md:p-0 w-full transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out border-b pb-10" x-cloak x-show="reportsOpen" x-collapse x-collapse.duration.500ms>
          This is a very simple dropdown/accordion/collapse (whatever you call it) using Tailwind, Alpine.js, and the Alpine.js plugin "Collapse" to enable smoother open/collapse transitions than what comes out of the box with Alpine.js
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">The goal of the exercise is to move information from the hidden and unknown quadrants into the open quadrant, thereby increasing self-awareness and understanding between individuals.</p>
</body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs a').click(function() {
      var tab = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.tab-content').hide();
      $(tab).show();
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>

</html>
```

The issue is that when setting the bg color for the  element only certain colors seem to work (black, white, red, yellow, blue, etc) but secondary colors (teal, emerald, slate, etc) don't work and I cannot understand why...

In the first snippet when setting the background of the  element to `bg-teal-600` the background is just white but when I set the color to Red for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Johari's Window Exercise</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@alpinejs/collapse@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-red-600">
  <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl m-4">Johari's Window</h1>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">Johari's window is an exercise that is used to improve self-awareness and understanding between individuals. It was created by psychologists Joseph Luft and Harry Ingham in 1955.</p>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">The exercise involves four quadrants, each representing a different aspect of an individual's self-awareness:</p>

  <div class='flex items-center justify-center' x-data="{ reportsOpen: false }">
    <div class='w-full max-w-lg px-10 py-8 mx-auto bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl'>
      <div class='max-w-md mx-auto space-y-6'>
        <img src='https://tailwindcomponents.com/svg/logo-color.svg' class='h-8' />

        <p class='text-gray-600'></p>

        <div @click="reportsOpen = !reportsOpen" class='flex items-center text-gray-600 w-full border-b overflow-hidden mt-32 md:mt-0 mb-5 mx-auto'>
          <div class='w-10 border-r px-2 transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out' :class="{'rotate-90': reportsOpen,' -translate-y-0.0': !reportsOpen }">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
                        </svg>
          </div>
          <div class='flex items-center px-2 py-3'>
            <div class='mx-3'>
              <button class="hover:underline">This is where you click to open</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex p-5 md:p-0 w-full transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out border-b pb-10" x-cloak x-show="reportsOpen" x-collapse x-collapse.duration.500ms>
          This is a very simple dropdown/accordion/collapse (whatever you call it) using Tailwind, Alpine.js, and the Alpine.js plugin "Collapse" to enable smoother open/collapse transitions than what comes out of the box with Alpine.js
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">The goal of the exercise is to move information from the hidden and unknown quadrants into the open quadrant, thereby increasing self-awareness and understanding between individuals.</p>
</body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs a').click(function() {
      var tab = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.tab-content').hide();
      $(tab).show();
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>

</html>
```

You can see that it works, any help in understanding this would be really appreciated, for clarity below I have also included the default `.css` file that Tailwind produced as well as my `tailwind.config.js` file.

```css
/*
! tailwindcss v3.2.4 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com
*/

/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  /* 2 */
  border-style: solid;
  /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
  /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
5. Use the user's configured `sans` font-feature-settings by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  -o-tab-size: 4;
     tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  /* 4 */
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  /* 5 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0;
  /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  font-weight: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 2 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}

/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input::-moz-placeholder, textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/

:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Make elements with the HTML hidden attribute stay hidden by default */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

::backdrop {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}
```

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,css}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: please attached `packaje.json` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `tailwind.min.css` file from cdn, which is a minimal version of the stuff tailwind provides and doesn't include all the styles (like teal color).

What you can do to resolve this is to import the fully css file from the tailwind cdn, just like the code below:

`<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Johari's Window Exercise</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@alpinejs/collapse@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-teal-700">
  <h1 class="font-bold text-4xl m-4">Johari's Window</h1>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">Johari's window is an exercise that is used to improve self-awareness and understanding between individuals. It was created by psychologists Joseph Luft and Harry Ingham in 1955.</p>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">The exercise involves four quadrants, each representing a different aspect of an individual's self-awareness:</p>

  <div class='flex items-center justify-center' x-data="{ reportsOpen: false }">
    <div class='w-full max-w-lg px-10 py-8 mx-auto bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl'>
      <div class='max-w-md mx-auto space-y-6'>
        <img src='https://tailwindcomponents.com/svg/logo-color.svg' class='h-8' />

        <p class='text-gray-600'></p>

        <div @click="reportsOpen = !reportsOpen" class='flex items-center text-gray-600 w-full border-b overflow-hidden mt-32 md:mt-0 mb-5 mx-auto'>
          <div class='w-10 border-r px-2 transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out' :class="{'rotate-90': reportsOpen,' -translate-y-0.0': !reportsOpen }">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
                        </svg>
          </div>
          <div class='flex items-center px-2 py-3'>
            <div class='mx-3'>
              <button class="hover:underline">This is where you click to open</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        Hi, buddy! Looks like you are using the `tailwind.min.css` file from cdn, witch is a minimal version of the things that tailwind provides and does not includes all styles (like special colors).
        What you can do to solve this is import the fully css file from the tailwind's cdn, just like the code below:
        ```
        <head>
          <title>Johari's Window Exercise</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" />
          <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
          <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@alpinejs/collapse@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
        </head>
        ```


        <div class="flex p-5 md:p-0 w-full transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out border-b pb-10" x-cloak x-show="reportsOpen" x-collapse x-collapse.duration.500ms>
          This is a very simple dropdown/accordion/collapse (whatever you call it) using Tailwind, Alpine.js, and the Alpine.js plugin "Collapse" to enable smoother open/collapse transitions than what comes out of the box with Alpine.js
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="font-normal m-4">The goal of the exercise is to move information from the hidden and unknown quadrants into the open quadrant, thereby increasing self-awareness and understanding between individuals.</p>
</body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs a').click(function() {
      var tab = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.tab-content').hide();
      $(tab).show();
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>

</html>
````

Please, see this document to learn how to extend tailwind settings from cdn: [https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn#:~:text=Try%20customizing%20your%20config](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn#:%7E:text=Try%20customizing%20your%20config)